# VBA How to Submit an Image filepath to database as Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, image, filepath

Looking for help on the right syntax to convert a image filepath string into a hyperlink when clicking a submit command button.

I am successfully able to submit the string into the right row and column but cannot figure out where to place the hyperlinks.add. Below is the code I have for submitting the strings to a database.

Anyway to add the hyperlinks.add method into the lines for filename 1 and 2?

filepath1 = the textbox where image1 control places filepath

filepath1 = the textbox where image2 control places the filepath.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TargetRow As Integer
TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("B3").Value + 1 
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 1) = orderid
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 2) = ComboBox1
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 3) = ComboBox2
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 4) = ComboBox3
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 5) = TextBox2
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 6) = TextBox3
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 7) = filepath1
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 8) = filepath2
Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks so much
April

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do it in two ways:

1 - You use your range inside the Hyperlink.Add function

```
'Use named range and use the offset directly in the Hyperlink.Add function
Sheets("Database").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 7), _
Address:=filepath1
```

2 - You define your range as a variable (linked_path) and use the variable in the Hyperlink.Add function

```
'Use named range and a variable in the Hyperlink.Add function
Set linked_path = Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 8)

Sheets("Database").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=linked_path, _
Address:=filepath2
```

---

---

**Test code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim filepath1 As String
Dim filepath2 As String
Dim linked_path As Variant
Dim orderid As Long
orderid = 1 'Test value for orderid

filepath1 = "G:\test\Stack Overflow\Book7.xlsx"
filepath2 = "G:\test\Stack Overflow\Book6.xlsx"

TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("B3").Value + 1
Sheets("Database").Range("E3").Offset(TargetRow, 1) = orderid
Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 1) = orderid
'.etc

'####### Hyperlink versions #######
'Data_Start is named range in Cell "C3". Cell C3 is named "Data_Start"

'Define static range (E3:E4)
Sheets("Database").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Database").Range("E3:E4").Offset(TargetRow, 8), _
 Address:=filepath2

'Use named range and use the offset directly in the Hyperlink.Add function
Sheets("Database").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 7), _
 Address:=filepath1

'Use named range and a variable in the Hyperlink.Add function
Set linked_path = Sheets("Database").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 8)

Sheets("Database").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=linked_path, _
 Address:=filepath2

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! I used the last option of creating a linked_path variable as it was cleaner to me. I appreciate all the different options you gave me. It's great to now understand how the hyperlink.add function can work with submitting data to a database. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Happy it worked :), You actually learned me about name reference "Data_Start". I tried and tried until I realized it was a named range in Excel. Then I have already test the different versions, so I thank you too :D. Take care!